# MATLAB Extracting Column Number

Tags: matlab

My goal is to create a random, 20 by 5 array of integers, sort them by increasing order from top to bottom and from left to right, and then calculate the mean in each of the resulting 20 rows. This gives me a 1 by 20 array of the means. I then have to find the column whose mean is closest to 0. Here is my code so far:

```
RandomArray= randi([-100 100],20,5);
NewArray=reshape(sort(RandomArray(:)),20,5);
MeanArray= mean(transpose(NewArray(:,:)))
X=min(abs(x-0))
```

How can I store the column number whose mean is closest to 0 into a variable? I'm only about a month into coding so this probably seems like a very simple problem. Thanks

Comment: Have a look in the docs at the second output of the `min` function. It gives you the index of the minimum rather than the value.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. All you need is a [`find`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
RandomArray= randi([-100 100],20,5);
NewArray=reshape(sort(RandomArray(:)),20,5);
% MeanArray= mean(transpose(NewArray(:,:))) %// gives means per row, not column
ColNum = find(abs(mean(NewArray,1))==min(abs(mean(NewArray,1)))); %// gives you the column number of the minimum
MeanColumn = RandomArray(:,ColNum);
```

`find` will give you the index of the entry where `abs(mean(NewArray))`, i.e. the absolute values of the mean per column equals the minimum of that same array, thus the index where the mean of the column is closest to `0`.

Note that you don't need your `MeanArray`, as it transposes (which can be done by `NewArray.'`, and then gives the mean per column, i.e. your old rows. I chucked everything in the `find` statement.

As suggested in the [comment by Matthias W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193967/matlab-extracting-column-number/35194210#comment58105256_35194210) it's faster to use the second output of [`min`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) directly instead of a `find`:

```
RandomArray= randi([-100 100],20,5);
NewArray=reshape(sort(RandomArray(:)),20,5);
% MeanArray= mean(transpose(NewArray(:,:))) %// gives means per row, not column
[~,ColNum] = min(abs(mean(NewArray,1)));
MeanColumn = RandomArray(:,ColNum);
```

Comment: `min` can also return the column index (no need for `find`) ;) -- `[MinVal,ColNum] = min(abs(mean(NewArray,1)))`